# Open office calc defaults to 19XX

Tags: openoffice, open

I'm using **Nuance 8.1 Pro pdf converter** to dump into Open Office `.xlsx`

It takes `12/15/15` and makes it `12/15/1915`.

I need a (4) digit year for the final result but need the right century.

Comment: http://www.nuance.com/support/pdf-converter/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Open the Tools→Options window.  If needed, expand the tree for "OpenOffice" by clicking on the + at the top left of the window.  Select "General" from the "OpenOffice" tree.

The bottom section of the window is labeled "Year (two digits)" and has a customizable setting for how it assigns a century to two-digit years.  Set it as you need for you application.